# Functional Component in React is not updating on props change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am new to react and I have created one listContactComp which shows the list and it has edit button to that specific element.
On the click on edit button I am calling editContactComp which is taking id as prop and fetching the specific contact data.

It gets fetched but not updated in the form.

Here is the code for editContactComp.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouteMatch} from "react-router-dom";
import ContactForm from "./ContactForm";

const EditContact = () => {
    const stateData = useRouteMatch();
    const contactId = stateData.params.contactId;
    console.log("insurer -> ", contactId);  //  gets printed
    const defContactData = {
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        status: false,
        address: ""
    }

    const [formDataUpdate, setContactData] = React.useState(defContactData);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchContact = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3008/fetchContact?id=${contactId}`);
            const contacts = await response.json();
            console.log("contact data ", contacts.data[0]);    // data is coming in array, oneElement
            setContactData(contacts.data[0]);
        }
        fetchContact();
    }, [contactId])

    const updateInsurer = async (contactData) => {
        console.log("edit contact");
        // update logic
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ContactForm contact={formDataUpdate} onSubmit={updateInsurer} />
        </>
    )
}

export default EditContact;
```

And contact form is :

```
const ContactForm = ({ contact, onSubmit }) => {
    console.log("from props ", contact);    // whole data is printed here
    const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState(contact);
    console.log("insurer form values", formData);   // only default data is printed here and shown in form

    return (
        <>
        ... whole form body
        </>
    )
}

export default ContactForm;
```

Comment: You have to use useEffect() again in ContactForm to get your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @rdr20 suggested: Try listening for changes on `contact` in `<ContactForm />` with the `useEffect()` hook.

```
const ContactForm = ({ contact, onSubmit }) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState(contact); // this runs only once, when the component is mounted, not when i.e. contact updates.
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setFormData(contact);
        }, [contact]) // now this listens to changes in contact

    return (
        <>
        ... whole form body
        </>
    )
}

export default ContactForm;
```